# How can I enable hibernation mode on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: hibernate, 21.04

I want to enable hibernation on Ubuntu 21.04. I have tried downloading `pm-utils` and running the command needed to. However, when I run the following command, nothing happens:

```
pm-hibernate
```

Comment: Just Google it. This is a FAQ and you will find plenty of guidance online.

Answer (score 0):

### To enable Hibernation in 21.04:

**Increase `swapfile` size to match RAM size up to 8GB.**

- Check the swap that is in use:

  ```
  sudo swapon -s
  ```
- If swap partition(s) are found:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add `#` before the `UUID` of the swap partition(s):

  ```
  # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
  ```
- Add a line for the `swapfile`, if one does not exist:

  ```
  /swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
  ```
- Create the `swapfile`:

  ```
  sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
  ```

  where `X` is `swapfile`'s size in GB:

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

**Add `resume` location and offset to `grub.cfg`:**

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"
  ```
- Use `UUID` from root.
- Use offset from:

  ```
  sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'
  ```
- Update GRUB:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Test hibernation:

  ```
  sudo systemctl hibernate
  ```

A hibernate button can be added using GNOME extensions.

Note that there is a slight possibility of getting holes in a `swapfile` when creating it with `fallocate`. `/var/log/syslog` can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

A swap file can alternatively be created using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
```

**An error when using `dd` may overwrite your HDD.**

Comment: When you write "Increase swapfile size to match RAM size up to 8GB", what would that for a machine with 32GB of RAM?

Comment: I usually find that 8GB RAM is enough to enable hibernate. If you have plenty of disk space, like multi terabytes, try 32GB swapfile. you can always switch back if you  don't need that much.